# Number pattern in c# form

Tags: c#, forms

I have the following method:

```cs
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i, j;
    string rows = "";

    for( i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            rows += (j+i);
        }
        rows += "\n";
    }
    label4.Text = rows;
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
0
12
234
4567
```

But should output the following:

```
0
12
345
6789
```

can you please help me?
But not for Console, I want to do it in Form.

Comment: `for(j = i+1;...`

Comment: Mr.Smurf I can't see your answer :'(

Comment: @Ilkin That is because he left it for you to work with. I think you would benefit by putting a breakpoint on the first for loop and stepping through your code. look at the values of `i` and `j` as they run through the loop. Once you understand why you are getting this result, you will have a much better idea of how you can fix it to get your desired output.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still stuck, this code should help. You can see how close you were as you were only missing one necessary variable.

```
int i, j;
int k = 0;
string rows = "";

for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
   for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
   {
       rows += k++;
   }
   rows += "\n";
}
label4.Text = rows;
```